# onclick after class change

Tags: jquery, html

Okay here is the deal. I am trying to build a website where an image changes when you click it. I came up with the following working code:

```
$(".follow").on("click", function(){
    $(".follow").attr("src", "../pictures/vriendverwijder.png");
$(".follow").addClass("unfollow");
$(".follow").removeClass("follow")

}); //onclick
```

In the above part i changed my class to unfollow. Now when the class is unfollow and you click it i want the picture to return to the previous picture. so i used this code:

```
$(".unfollow").on("click", function(){
    $(".unfollow").attr("src", "../pictures/vriendtoevoeg.png");
$(".unfollow").addClass("follow");
$(".unfollow").removeClass("unfollow")

}); //onclick
```

The picture won`t change however. I know there are multiple topics on this changing pictures stuff but i do not understand them. Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like an impractical way to handle this. Seeing as your image is static, why not just use toggleClass and have the toggled style override the original?

Comment: Side note: Have you ever used `$(this)`?

Comment: Or assign a click function to the image `img src="..." onclick="..."` and have the called function change it's class?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted? It has a good explanation of the issue and shows the OPs attempts to solve it himself.

Comment: @KaiQing you can't change `src` of an `img` via a CSS class.

Comment: @Rory - I'm not suggesting he can. I'm saying he should change to css handled images because it looks like he is using static images and they can be combined into a sprite sheet for better optimization anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are binding event handlers to elements with specific classes *at the time the event is bound*.

Use delegated event handlers instead as the class is changing dynamically:

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', ".follow", function(){
   $(".follow").attr("src", "../pictures/vriendverwijder.png");
   $(".follow").addClass("unfollow");
   $(".follow").removeClass("follow")
});

$(document).on('click', ".unfollow", function(){
    $(".unfollow").attr("src", "../pictures/vriendtoevoeg.png");
    $(".unfollow").addClass("follow");
    $(".unfollow").removeClass("unfollow")
});
```

*These can be combined into a single handler if you apply it to another unchanging class (as Rory has added)*

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because when the page loads the element has the `follow` class, so the event handlers for `unfollow` are not bound.

You could instead have a common class to attach the events to and a flag class to determine state, something like this:

```
<img class="foo follow" src="../pictures/vriendverwijder.png" />
```

```js
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
    var src = $(this).hasClass('follow') ? "../pictures/vriendverwijder.png" : "../pictures/vriendtoevoeg.png";
    $(this).attr("src", src);
    $(this).toggleClass("unfollow follow")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are expecting a click listener to bind to any added styles. This is not the standard behavior. As TrueBlueAussie mentioned, you can use .on to listen on newly created items as well, but ultimately I think your approach could be simplified...

Change your listener to this:

```
$(".follow").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('unfollow');
});
```

And have your CSS override the standard style when unfollowed is paired with follow:

```
.follow{
    background-image{
        url(/path-to-image.png);
    }
}

.follow.unfollow{
    background-image{
        url(/path-to-alternate-image.png);
    }
}
```

PS - I imply changing images to background images handled by css since they look static. You can even combine them into a sprite sheet and just offset the background-position to minimize http load requests.

Say, for example, your follow element is an anchor tag, which is normally not a block level element...

```
<a href="#" class="follow"></a>
```

Your css could be:

```
.follow{
    display:block;
    width:45px;
    height:20px;
    background: url(/pictures/vriendverwijder.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
}

.follow.unfollow{
    background-position:0 -20px;
}
```

and your image could be a single png prepared like so... (sorry for the ascii art)

```
------------------------
|    normal state       |
------------------------  40px high
|    active state       |
------------------------
         45 px wide
```

Comment: I prefer this as a cleaner approach to Rory's +1